# Replace a part of string using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable as below

```
var a = "Hi this is test. <img src='http://www.test.com/img1.jpg'> Test ends here";
```

I want to replace the `src` of image tag to some other image url lets say `http://www.test2.com/img2.jpg`

So the output should be

```
var b = "Hi this is test. <img src='http://www.test2.com/img2.jpg'> Test ends here";
```

Both the image path would be dynamic.

Please help.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that's really what you want to do? Are you going to set that string as innerHTML? 'cause it'd be easier to just do that, then change the image element's src attribute using the DOM. Otherwise, you'll have to find the index positions and do some substringing and concating.

Comment: I am plannning to pass that to php using ajax and then do it but if it can be done using JS then much better

Answer (score 6):

You can set the url of the image by making it a jquery object, like so:

```
var $myImg = $("<img src='http://www.test.com/img1.jpg'>");
$myImg.attr("src","http://www.test2.com/img2.jpg");
```

Comment: the image path1 and path2 will be dynamic. Also in my case i would know path2 but wont have any idea about path1 what it is. so this wont work.

Comment: You can use a variable to set the src as well if you want, I don't see the problem. What exactly do you mean by "the image path1 and path2 will be dynamic" ?

Comment: $myImg is an object. Now i want to save it into a variable so how exactly it would go?

Comment: If you want just the html you can use $.myImage.wrap("div").parent().html() , but you are probably better off to use the jQuery functions prepend or append if you want to introduce the element into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pnwKs/

Depending on how you want to change the url, you can use the attr command.

```
// changes the full SRC path
$('#1').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/350x250');


// replaces some part of the SRC path
$('#2').attr('src', $('#1').attr('src').replace('250','400'));
```

If it's inside a string you could do:

```
var a = "Hi this is test. <img src='http://www.test.com/img1.jpg'> Test ends here";
a.replace('img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/Ww2Lu/
You can change the src just passing the new one thrue the param.